# Manga where mc has to work at an all female fortress being the only guy

Tags: story-identification, manga

The story starts where he has to do some kind of ritual to determine his skill or something. Then people see he either had no skill or a trash one he gets assigned to work for the 3rd princess I think and her whole fort/battalion is just women.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Also, if anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

This is probably *[Medical Examination Record of the Fallen Spirits Doctor: Holy Knights and the Divine Work of Healing](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/hagure-seireii-no-shinsatsu-kiroku-seijo-kishi-dan-to-iyashi-no-kamiwaza)*

> Glas loses his path in life when **he pulls a "flop" during his spirit summoning ceremony**. However, he is given another chance when he receives a royal order to fight in the front lines, along with the **Princess's knights**, as a war doctor. With his "flop" capable of curing anything, the curtains unfold upon a new fantasy war chronicle!

The synopsis covers the trash skill part of the question. Afterwards, he continues to study as a doctor and gets high marks, but is still discriminated against due to his useless skill. He is then recruited by royal order to become a doctor by the Second Princess, in a power play for succession against the Third Princess.

[image: Princess exposition]

On the way there he is told that the fort where he'll be working is all-female.

[image: Female only exposition]

Found by searching mangaupdates for the `seemingly useless power` tag and filtering genre to include Harem.