# Manga where the main character is a healer, and now must be a medic/healer type, in an all or mostly female army

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character being somewhat looked down upon since he was a prodigy, but he turned out to excel in healing magic. So he's appointed as a healer/medic type of role in an all-woman army.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably *[Medical Examination Record of the Fallen Spirits Doctor: Holy Knights and the Divine Work of Healing](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/hagure-seireii-no-shinsatsu-kiroku-seijo-kishi-dan-to-iyashi-no-kamiwaza)*, also identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264012).

> Glas loses his path in life when he pulls a "flop" during his spirit summoning ceremony. However, he is given another chance when he receives a royal order to fight in the front lines, along with the Princess's knights, as a war doctor. With his "flop" capable of curing anything, the curtains unfold upon a new fantasy war chronicle!

The "looked down upon because he was a prodigy" part is a bit off, as he was looked down upon for having a seemingly terrible skill. He does get high marks while at school, but the skill is what matters in these stories.

On the way to the fort he is told that it is all-female.

[image: Female only exposition]